# cp command does not overwrite existing files

Tags: cp

I'm copying files from a git repository into a virtualhost folder, although none of the following commands do overwrite existing files:

```
sudo cp -R /home/git/repo /var/www/website
sudo cp -R -f /home/git/repo /var/www/website
```

How can I make sure the `cp` command overwrites existing files?

Edit: Quick test, copying files from the webdir to the repo does overwrite files, so apparently something (`www-data?`) is locking the files in the webdir. The `mount` output:

```
~$ mount | column -t
sysfs       on  /sys                             type  sysfs       (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc        on  /proc                            type  proc        (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev        on  /dev                             type  devtmpfs    (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=1005964k,nr_inodes=251491,mode=755)
devpts      on  /dev/pts                         type  devpts      (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs       on  /run                             type  tmpfs       (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=204840k,mode=755)
/dev/vda1   on  /                                type  ext4        (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
securityfs  on  /sys/kernel/security             type  securityfs  (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs       on  /dev/shm                         type  tmpfs       (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs       on  /run/lock                        type  tmpfs       (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs       on  /sys/fs/cgroup                   type  tmpfs       (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup      on  /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd           type  cgroup      (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
pstore      on  /sys/fs/pstore                   type  pstore      (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup      on  /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb           type  cgroup      (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
cgroup      on  /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer           type  cgroup      (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup      on  /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct       type  cgroup      (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup      on  /sys/fs/cgroup/memory            type  cgroup      (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup      on  /sys/fs/cgroup/devices           type  cgroup      (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup      on  /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio  type  cgroup      (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
cgroup      on  /sys/fs/cgroup/pids              type  cgroup      (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
cgroup      on  /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio             type  cgroup      (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup      on  /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset            type  cgroup      (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup      on  /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event        type  cgroup      (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
systemd-1   on  /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc         type  autofs      (rw,relatime,fd=27,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct)
debugfs     on  /sys/kernel/debug                type  debugfs     (rw,relatime)
mqueue      on  /dev/mqueue                      type  mqueue      (rw,relatime)
hugetlbfs   on  /dev/hugepages                   type  hugetlbfs   (rw,relatime)
fusectl     on  /sys/fs/fuse/connections         type  fusectl     (rw,relatime)
tmpfs       on  /run/user/1000                   type  tmpfs       (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=204840k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
```

And:

```
df -h /var/www
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda1        30G   20G  8.9G  69% /
```

Comment: Did the above command give you an error or a message? Try adding the `-v` option to understand better the problem.

Comment: No errors are given. `-v` option shows all files being copied, but again, not overwritten.

Comment: The output of `mount` may help a lot.  I suspect a network mount that may be configured in strange ways.

Comment: Are you using the genuine `cp` command (i.e. `/usr/bin/cp`), or is `cp` an alias, such as `cp -n`?

Comment: `cp` is not an alias. Tested it with `\cp` and `alias cp` That last one returned `-bash: alias: cp: not found`

Comment: Do you have a selinux installed? **getenforce** should tell you.

Comment: No. `~$ getenforce The program 'getenforce' is currently not installed`

Comment: 1. Can you give an example of a file that's not being overwritten, please, with the output from its `ls -l {file}` and `df -h {file}` (yes, really. `df` with the file's pathname, eg `df -h /etc/hosts`) 2. Can you overwrite that file with e.g. `sudo cp /etc/hosts {file}` (you may want to save the real file's contents and replace it afterwards).

Comment: Might be stupid question, please don't feel offended, but are you sure you are copying data to the location you really want to? Commands you specified should copy repo folder to /var/www/website/repo. Hope this is what you wanted to achieve. I don't believe linux is copying data and silently drops it. Any message? You could also add **-v** switch to your copy command to see what is going on.

Comment: @roaima `ls -l index.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 98151 Oct 20 12:56 index.html`

Comment: @Kalavan: Yes, for testing purpose we copy everthing to a subfolder of /var/www/website.

Comment: @KurtVandenBranden and the `df` please, just as I described

Comment: Typo edit: `df -h /var/www/website/repo/index.html` returns `/dev/vda1 30G 20G 8.8G 69% /`

Comment: ... So what happens instead? Error messages, cp -v, strace, lsattr?

Comment: Reduce the problem to a single or a few files (so they fit sanely in the question), the do an `ls -l` on the source files, and on the destination files before and after the copy. And post the commands you entered exactly. Something like 'ls -l /home/git/repo/foo ; ls -l /var/www/website/repo/foo ; cp -a  /home/git/repo /var/www/website/ ;  ls -l /var/www/website/repo/foo`

Comment: As it is now, the question doesn't even show the files involved. Comments are a really bad way of adding information, as the formatting doesn't work well. (Also the `ls -l` listing a couple of comments up doesn't show where that `index.html` is located.)

Comment: Is the server also running an NFS (server)? If so please show `/etc/exports`.  Or is Samba running?  Please also check what could be locking the file: `fuser -v  /var/www/website/repo/index.html`.

Comment: From someone who's opened a bounty, I would expect a *little* more effort to include the details.  Change your prompt, if you like, with `PS1='\$ '`, and then show the *entire* terminal output *concisely* that illustrates the difficulty you are having.  Many good suggestions in the comments on how to do this, but the point is that it should be possible from reading the terminal output alone to see what your problem is.

Answer (score 3):

#### Instead of `cp` I prefer use `tar` for big tree..

Yes, I use near never `cp -r` syntaxe (except for hardlinking backups, with `cp -al`, but it's very specific).

Syntax of tar do permit a lot of finest configuration for copying big tree, about what could be or not copied (which files, permissions, owner...) see `man tar`.

I prefer to be familiar with `tar` command:

On localhost:

```
 tar -cpC /path/to/source . | tar -xpC /path/to/target
```

(note the dot `.` which specify *what to save*).

Be familiar with `tar` could be usefull for remote copy:

```
ssh user@remotesource tar -zcpC /path/to/source . | tar -zxpC /path/to/target
```

or

```
tar -zcpC /path/to/source . | ssh user@targethost tar -zxpC /path/to/target
```

or even

```
ssh user@remotesource tar -zcpC /path/to/source . |
    ssh user@targethost tar -zxpC /path/to/target
```

On remote and/or different hosts, while copying users account, you may like `--numeric-owner` options...

- `--one-file-system` stay in local file system
- `--overwrite` overwrite existing files
- `-T, --files-from FILE` get names to extract or create from FILE
- `-z` use gzip compression

#### Instead of `tar`, why not using `cpio`

As [imz -- Ivan Zakharyaschev](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/559335?noredirect=1) commented out, `cpio` could do same, but not with same syntax:

`cpio` require list of inode (file, dir, dev, socket, fifo) that must be stored in *archive* to be submitted by *`STDIN`*.

But `cpio` offer a mode *`--pass-through`* wich let you copy file to another directory.

This make syntaxe stronger, but as we use `find` to build this list, we could use power of `find` to copy exactly what we need:

```
cd /path/to/source
find . \( -type f -o -type d \) ! -name '*.foo' -print0 | 
    cpio --null -pvd /path/to/destination
```

Used remotely, you could:

```
ssh user@remotesource /bin/sh <<<'cd /path/to/source;
    find . \( -type f -o -type d \) ! -name '*.foo' -print0 |
    cpio --null -o |
    gzip' |
  ssh user@targethost 'cd /path/to/destination && gunzip | cpio -id'
```

Comment: `cpio` can be similarly useful

Comment: @imz--IvanZakharyaschev Hmm No: cpio require list of node to by backed up by standard input. Don't have a recursive mode. But yes, you could do same by using cpio... with some more work: `ssh source /bin/sh <<<'cd /source/path && find . | cpio -o | gzip' | gunzip | cpio -i`

Comment: rsync can be similarly useful

Comment: @user1133275 yes, but `tar` and `cpio` is installed with linux standard base. `rsync` is a strong tool not installed by default everywhere. But yes, this could be done with `rsync` in very insteresting ways. (This is no more only *copying*, but  *syncing*!)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are running this as root (using `sudo`), have you checked if there is an alias for `cp` in root's `.bashrc` or `.profile`?
Something like:

```
alias cp="cp -i"
```

Try to run the commands with '`\`', like this:

```
sudo \cp -R /home/git/repo /var/www/website
```

The `\` in `\cp` will make `cp` run without any alias.

Comment: I doubt it's about that, `cp -i` should ask about overwriting, instead of silently skipping, and `-f` should override `-i`. Also, most shells don't expand aliases when running non-interactively, in bash it's controlled by `shopt expand_aliases` which is set by default (only) on interactive shells. Also, `.bashrc` isn't read by non-interactive shells either. You can test that with doing something like `bash -c 'alias ls="ls -l"; ls'`. Actually I don't think `sudo` even runs a shell to execute a command line like that, but runs the command by itself. (try `sudo alias`)

Comment: Yeah, you're right. `cp -i` should prompt before overwriting.

Comment: `\cp` does not do the trick. The files are not overwritten.

Comment: @KurtVandenBranden Sorry buddy, at this point I am out of ideas!

Comment: `cp -u` but this only works, when the Files that you are copy are newer, than the existing.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want the files to end up in `/var/www/website/index.html`, but with the above syntax, they'll end up in `/var/www/website/repo/index.html`.

You can verify if this is indeed happening by checking whether you have a `/var/www/website/repo/` directory with new files.

The solution would be to use something like `cp -R source/* dest/`, or maybe a `rsync -a source/ dest/` to be more efficient.

Comment: Yes. And additionally to `cp -R source/* dest/` or `rsync -a source/ dest/`, one other could help here: `cp -R source -T dest`

Comment: As stated before in one of the comments: For testing purpose, we copy everything to a subfolder of /var/www/website.

Comment: @KurtVandenBranden you stated in a comment earlier you want to operate on `/var/www/website/index.html`. Is that not true? Please clarify your question, it's apparent that several people now don't understand what you're actually asking.

Comment: @KurtVandenBranden a good place to start would be pasting the exact output of a command that shows the previous state of the directory you want to update, and the exact output of the command that shows you the new state after the update.

Answer (score 1):

Permissions and ownership may matter on your files, but if you don't need anything but `644` and `755` all by the same owner, you could just check out directly from Git:

```
git --git-dir=/home/git/repo/.git --work-tree=/var/www/website checkout -f HEAD
```

The `-f` flag forces the checkout, causing Git to overwrite any changes in `/var/www/website` with the version saved in Git.

`HEAD` is of course the pointer to Git's idea of the "current" commit.

---

You could also explore the `git worktree` command, but since you won't be doing *development* in `/var/www/website`, the above is likely more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend trying `sudo cp -Rf /home/git/repo/* /var/www/website`, I've always had better luck myself when copying contents of directories instead of directories.